# How To Create a Temp Table Out of Column Contents

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a contents field that is populated with IDs of items on that page. Like this:

```
ID                | Contents
Section-page-id   |  item-1 item-2 item-3 item-4 item-5
Section-page-id2  |  item-6 item-7 item-8 item-9 item-10
```

I would like to create a temp table that looks like the following:

```
Section-id       |ID
item-1           |Section-page-id 
item-2           |Section-page-id 
item-3           |Section-page-id 
item-4           |Section-page-id 
item-5           |Section-page-id 
item-6           |Section-page-id2 
item-7           |Section-page-id2 
item-8           |Section-page-id2 
item-9           |Section-page-id2 
item-10          |Section-page-id2
```

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This is a poor design. When you stuff multiple values into a single column like this it violates 1NF and is a serious pain to work with. You need a string splitter to parse this into something usable. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: There are lots of well documented answers on the subject of how to split a delimited string into rows.  On this site and others.  Recursive Common Table Expression Method, Table Valued Functions, XML.  What have you searched and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

From [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows):

```
Declare @YourTable table
(
ID varchar(50),
Contents varchar(max)
)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Section-page-id','item-1 item-2 item-3 item-4 item-5'),
('Section-page-id2','item-6 item-7 item-8 item-9 item-10')


;WITH CTE (ID, SectionId, Contents)  as (

select ID, LEFT(Contents, CHARINDEX(' ',Contents+' ')-1),
    STUFF(Contents, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',Contents+' '), '')
from @YourTable
union all
select ID, LEFT(Contents, CHARINDEX(' ',Contents+' ')-1),
    STUFF(Contents, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',Contents+' '), '')
from CTE
where Contents > ''
)
select SectionId, ID
from CTE
order by ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly and will be of major benefit.